# C read/write and clear FILE

Tags: c, file, io

this might sound like a dumb question, but I understand `fopen(fileLoc, r+);` opens an existing file and allows both read and write operations to this file.  However, how would I get `fopen` to clear the file aswell, to allow `w` like write access to clear file, but also allows read access, I have tried `r+w` but it doesnt seem to work properly.

So I need essentially both `fopen(fileLoc, r);` and `fopen(fileLoc, w);` access to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fopen(fileLoc, w+)` should do it. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/fopen

Update: Also, you might need to call positioning function (like `fseek()` or `fgetpos()`) in between the output and input operations, in accordance with the ANSI C standard: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Comment: That allows me to write and clear a text file, but it does not properly read the contents once written to FILE

Comment: @Sean: No problemo :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try fopen(fileLoc, w+) for both reading and writing.